# How to verify that app was signed by my certificate?

Tags: android, security, certificate

How do I check if the signature of my app matches the signature of the certificate that I used to sign it?

This is how I should be able to get the certificates fingerprint:

```
public String getCertificateFingerprint() throws NameNotFoundException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        String packageName =context.getPackageName();

        int flags = PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES;

        PackageInfo packageInfo = null;

        packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, flags);
        Signature[] signatures = packageInfo.signatures;

        byte[] cert = signatures[0].toByteArray();

        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(cert);

        CertificateFactory cf = null;
        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");

        X509Certificate c = null;
        c = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(input);

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] publicKey = md.digest(c.getPublicKey().getEncoded());

        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < publicKey.length; i++) {
            String appendString = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & publicKey[i]);
            if (appendString.length() == 1)
                hexString.append("0");
            hexString.append(appendString);
        }

        return hexString.toString();
    }
```

This is how I should be able to get the fingerprint of my certificate:

```
keytool -v -list -keystore filenameandpath
```

My problem is, that these two give back different results.
Could someone point out what I'm screwing up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are computing the MD5 hash of the wrong data. The fingerprint of a certificate is a hash (MD5, SHA1, SHA256, etc.) of the raw certificate. I.e., you should be computing the hash of these bytes:

```
byte[] cert = signatures[0].toByteArray();
```

E.g., the following computes a SHA1 fingerprint, just change SHA1 to MD5 if you prefer.

```
    public String computeFingerPrint(final byte[] certRaw) {

    String strResult = "";

    MessageDigest md;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        md.update(certRaw);
        for (byte b : md.digest()) {
            strAppend = Integer.toString(b & 0xff, 16);
            if (strAppend.length() == 1)
                strResult += "0";
            strResult += strAppend;
        }
        strResult = strResult.toUpperCase(DATA_LOCALE);
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return strResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open the apk as a zip file and filter the ascii text from the binary content of META-INF/CERT.RSA and check there is it you who singed it.

---

try:

```
final void  initVerify(Certificate certificate)
```

from: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/Signature.html

Comment: ascii text inside: "test". I'm pretty sure I signed it properly

Comment: @Tamas it means that it isn't singed

Comment: nope, I did sign it with a key I created for testing, so I filled out the company name etc with "test" :) so I did sign my app properly. So my problem still persists, I want to be able to validate in runtime, what certificate the apk has been signed with.

Comment: @Tamas try initVerify, as in my edited post maybe it'll works

Answer (score 0):

Use your code for collecting the fingerprint on the device in "test" mode -- meaning you have temporary code to emit that fingerprint to the log (or elsewhere). Be sure to test this using your production signing key, not the debug key!

Once you know from the device's perspective, you can remove the temporary code and elsewhere you can compare to what you've previously determined to be the key.

Be aware though that you're probably doing this to prevent someone from modifying your app and re-signing it with another key, but someone with the ability to do that also has the ability to modify your key checking. This is a problem that can be addressed with additional obfuscation but you'll need to come up with your own solution to minimize the chance of an attacker knowing what to look for.

Comment: yes, my goal would be to make it harder to re-sign the app. My problem is that I already have a code to query the fingerprint of the app, but it differs from what I think it should be.

Answer (score 0):

the code below:

```
 c.getPublicKey().getEncoded()
```

it should be like this

```
 c.getEncoded()
```

i think md5 check by keytool is check the certfile,not the publickey