# Check for "unlocker" in my free app?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

my music theory app is free and has no ads. I made this for a school project, the goal is to make some money. My idea is that some functions are only available if you have purchased the "unlocker" version of my app.

Can I tell my app to check for the "unlocker" at first launch? I don't want the "unlocker" app to act as the real app, just a "file" that unlocks the free version.

If the user has purchased the "unlocker" I want it to activate some locked buttons.

I would prefer it to work like for example Solid Explorer.

[Solide Explorer (Trial) - Google Play](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer)

[Solide Explorer Unlocker - Google Play](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer.unlocker)

Comment: Or use [In App Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html) and skip the second app users have to download and the additional checking that you'll need to do to confirm that the second app is legitimate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PackageManager.getPackageInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and request [PakageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) for your unlocker app. The app must be there. Second step would be to validate your [app's signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548756/how-to-verify-that-app-was-signed-by-my-certifiicate). To make it even more difficult to hack, your main app can send some intents to unlock app, and then receive and check responses for correctness.

Although this will technically work, it is not as safe as [In App Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html), which is advised way to go. Moreover in your case users will have to install two apps, which is not as convenient.